# Using arrays to blit multiple objects in pygame?

Tags: python, arrays, pygame, blit

I was looking for a faster way to blit multiple objects in pygame than the traditional blitting method, in which you have an array or list, and you use a for loop to go and insert each image at its position.

Maybe there is a way of blitting the whole array at once, without having to go value by value throughout the whole array?

Thanks for the ideas and help!

Comment: Are you using [Sprite groups?](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

Comment: No, I dont even know what that is. I have always used the blits, so for example: DisplaySurf.blit(myImage, (x,y))

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.sprite.Group` should do the trick! Also,
`pygame.sprite.Group` has a draw function that draws all sprites in a group.
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group

Answer (score 1):

use `pygame.sprite.Group` or multithread the blit method. In pygame 1.9.2alpha, it releases the python gil and allows multi-cpu rendering.

Also look up for pygame dirty rendering. Depending on what you want to draw, this can give you significant speed increase.